# How to save textview content to .txt file?

Tags: android, eclipse, textview

I want to save my TextView content in .txt file.
Anybody having any idea related to this,please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try Something like below:

```
String textToSaveString = textview.getText().tostring();

        writeToFile(textToSaveString);

        String textFromFileString =  readFromFile();

        if ( textToSaveString.equals(textFromFileString) )
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "both string are equal", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        else
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "there is a problem", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    private void writeToFile(String data) {
        try {
            OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
            outputStreamWriter.write(data);
            outputStreamWriter.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "File write failed: " + e.toString());
        }

    }

    private String readFromFile() {

        String ret = "";

        try {
            InputStream inputStream = openFileInput(FILENAME);

            if ( inputStream != null ) {
                InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
                String receiveString = "";
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

                while ( (receiveString = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null ) {
                    stringBuilder.append(receiveString);
                }

                inputStream.close();
                ret = stringBuilder.toString();
            }
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "File not found: " + e.toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Can not read file: " + e.toString());
        }

        return ret;
    }
```

Comment: Thanx for ur help,it really helped me.but I'm not able to find the saved file in mobile's internal storage. Where do I find it?